# Fix nav bar on top on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to achieve something similar to [here](http://avocode.com/features/export/)

but for me its not fixing at top on scrolling down.Someone please provide any example or resources to achieve this feature.

```
     .features-switcher.fixed:after,
      {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 101;
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1
    }
```

For my nav-bar div class `features-switcher`:

```
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            console.log("scrolled down");
            console.log($(window).scrollTop());
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
                $('features-switcher').css('top', 0);
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? What have you tried? Where does it fail?

Comment: added code .. I tried using css:after tag

Comment: I would do it using javascript to detect on scroll event when `window.scrollTop` is higher than you need set CSS `position:fixed;`(as well as `top` and other properties) to your nav bar, and set other CSS when `window.scrollTop` is smaller than that.

Comment: Yeah I also tried that .. look for change in code.But it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `.`

`$('features-switcher').css('top', 0);`

Should be...

`$('.features-switcher').css('top', 0);`